# Overriding CSS media queries

Tags: css, sass, media

I have a library that I'm using that applies `col-xxl-*` (where * is a number) style whenever the screen reaches `1600px`, that is `@media (min-width: 1600px)`.

Is there a way (without forking the library), to change this thing, so the `col-xxl-*` is applied from e.g. `2000px`?

Maybe helpful - this library is using `.less` with variables

Answer (score 4):

You have mentioned less with variables. Your media query is getting applied at 1600, which means there must be a configuration where variables are defined for

```
"xxl" : 1600px
```

You need to modify those variables and include it in less/scss file  before the library path is included. Check below code:

Variables.scss

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  // Extra small screen / phone
  xs: 0,
  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 576px,
  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 768px,
  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 992px,
  // Extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1280px,
  xxl: 2000px
);
```

app.scss:

```
@import "variables";
@import "{{librarypath}}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be this is work for you 
Just you have to overwrite in this media query using !important keyword this is not rightway but you are using libarary in that we could not overwrite and if we overwrite in our .less then it would not work so there is only way to use !important keyword in your media query @media (min-width: 2000px)